# Can I get country code from user's phone number of 11-digit like 03xx-xxxxxxx ? If it is possible then how?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the country code of user's phone number, he may have entered his/her phone without country code (11-digit).If it is possible then please help me out.

Comment: You have the power https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Alphabetical_listing_by_country_or_region

Comment: Or if you want to use Googles phonenumber lib `PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phone, ""); int countryCode = numberProto.getCountryCode();`

Answer (score 1):

There's a great library called `libphonenumber` (C# port: https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp) which does convert phone numbers into valid E.164 numbers. However, you need to assume the number's origin country to correctly parse them.

```
public string ParsePhoneNumber(string number)
{
    var phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
    return phoneNumberUtil.Parse(nationalPhoneNumber, "DE");
}
```